# a word or phrasal verb meaning "to reduce the complexity of a concept"

Tags: word-request, verbs

I want to say:

> To be a good teacher, one needs to X some concepts.

In place of X, I can only think of "attenuate", which means to lessen the severeness of a disease. But I want to say 'to make a complex concept simpler'. Is there a verb for my purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verb **simplify**, derived from the adjective 'simple' works here:

> to make simple or simpler: such as
>   ...
>   **b :** to diminish in scope or complexity : streamline
>   // was urged to *simplify* management procedures

<sub>(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/simplify))</sub>